# OneNote 2013 crashes when trying to merge sections

Tags: crash, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I keep my Laptop in sync with my desktop using SyncThing. Sometimes I get merge conflicts and I get the .sync-conflict section created for the conflicted section. I'd like to merge this in with the normal section, but OneNote crashes when i try it. The crash happens on both boxes.

I tried to delete the cache but that didn't solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: I just did the same on OneNote 2016 hoping it would be fixed. Same crash.